# CSS3 Multi column functionality in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any Internet Explorer workaround for multi column. I would like to achieve something like the following example:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

The above works well for Gecko browsers but not for Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: don't support terrible browsers.

Unfortunately while this may be an option with personal sites, or sites targeting a young or tech-savvy crowd, this is not a viable option for any sort of professional site.

What you can do is use a high-level library, which uses javascript to simulate the CSS3 specification, or some non-standard variant of the spec. Such libraries are often available as jQuery addons. e.g. http://welcome.totheinter.net/2008/07/22/multi-column-layout-with-css-and-jquery/ (though it doesn't seem to be forward-compatible with CSS3)